# Move min, max, close buttons to the left in Qt windows

Tags: 23.10, qt5, titlebar, window-buttons

Gnome allows to move Min, Max and Close buttons on the left of the title bar.
But Qt5 windows don't care (for instance: Clementine, KeepassXC, ...). And there is no option in Qt5 parameters to change this behaviour.

How is it possible to have all windows with buttons on the left of the title bar?

Comment: You've not provided any OS/release (inc. desktop) details, but I control where placement is via the WM controls (which includes `clementine` which is an app I use).

Comment: Added the OS in tags : Ubuntu 23.10